# A proof of Theorem 9.2.12. in the Gompf-Stipsicz

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, 4-manifolds, cobordism

I'm seeking for a proof of Theorem 9.2.12. in the Gompf-Stipsicz "*4-Manifolds and Kirby Calculus*" (for the statement, see the following image). But the textbook omits any proofs and only gives a weaker version (Theorem 9.2.13.). My question is:

**How can we find a proof of the theorem?**

Any references will be fine. Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: See, e.g., *The Wide World of 4-Manifolds* by A. Scorpan ([**google books**](https://books.google.com/books?id=VgG9AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA155&)) for a recent exposition of the Wall reference and its corollaries (p. 155, linked).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The weaker version is a result due to Wall:

> C.T.C. Wall,
>   [*On simply connected 4-manifolds*](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/w4.pdf),
>   J. London Math. Soc., **39** (1964), 141–149

A stronger statement has been proven by Kreck (who also gives some references), but I don't know about the original reference Gompf and Stipsicz were thinking about.

> Matthias Kreck,
>   [*h-cobordisms between 1-connected 4-manifolds*](http://www.emis.de/journals/UW/gt/ftp/main/2001/2001-1.pdf)
>   Geom. Topol., **5** (2001), 1-6

Comment: @Golla Yes, I have already learned that, if two simply-connected closed 4-manifolds have the same intersection form, then they are h-cobordant. But I really need now is "functorial h-cobordism" (satisfying $\varphi_W=\varphi$ , see the attached image). Where can we find this statement in the Wall's paper?

Comment: You're right. I added another reference (to a stronger statement).

Comment: @Golla Thank you for your kindness.